# how to put errorbars for a curve fitting graph?

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting, scatter-plot, errorbar

I am so new to MATLAB. I could draw my curve fitting graphs by using the mean of all my data through MATLAB. Now, I want to have errorbars on my Y datas. I have two questions now: 
1- how should I give and define errorbar order in MATLAB?
2- how should I organize my data in the EXCEL file? I mean, should I put the repetitions in columns?

My graphs are scatter plats and my own order in MATLAB is as follows:

```
 A=xlsread('C:\Users\Sara\Desktop\book');
 x=A(:,1);
 y=A(:,2);
 f=fit(x,y,'k*x^n')
 plot(f,'--',x,y,'o');
 xlabel('Time (min)')
 ylabel('qt(ppm)')
 d=fit(x,y,'(q*k*x)/(1+k*x)')
 hold on
 plot(d,'b:',x,y, 'o');
 legend('exp','pseudo','off','first')
 legend('exp','pseudo','exp','first')
```

Thanks so much.

Comment: Would be easier to help you if you shared the excel file. Regardless, I would suggest looking at the `errorbar()` function https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/errorbar.html

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I want to share my sample data in Excel, but I do not know how to share it here. My data is as follows:

0 0
0 0
0 0
2 0.0853
2 0.089
2 0.08
5 0.3398
5 0.3248
5 0.331
10 0.6197
10 0.6
10 0.6166
15 0.9558
15 0.959
15 0.8923
20 1.003
20 1
20 1.0045
25 1.011
25 1.01
25 1.021
30 1.001
30 1.011
30 1.011

Thanks again.

Comment: After running these, the models don't seem to fit quite well, you should try giving some initial values to the coefficients and maybe try a different model? Chemistry isn't my strong suit but are those models representative to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I've come up with, let me know if it's what you needed:

```
% Housekeeping
close all, clc

% Extract the data
x = A(:,1);
y = A(:,2);

% New data, comment out if you don't want to do this
for i=1:length(x)/3
    idx = (i-1)*3+1;
    x2(i) = mean(x(idx:(idx+2)));
    y2(i) = mean(y(idx:(idx+2)));
end

% Comment this if you want to use your original x and y
x = x2';
y = y2';



% Fit the data with model 1
f = fit(x,y,'k*x^n');
plot(x,y,'bo'), hold on
err = abs(f(y)-y); % Compute the error
% the err/2 is because it seems like error bar will do +-error so the
% length of the bar is twice the error
errorbar(x,y,err/2) % Plot the error
plot(x,f(y),'r--'), hold on
legend('data','error bars','model 2')
xlabel('Time (min)'), ylabel('qt(ppm)')

% Fit the data with model 2
figure
plot(x,y,'go'), hold on
d = fit(x,y,'(q*k*x)/(1+k*x)');
err = abs(d(y)-y); % Compute the error
errorbar(x,y,err/2) % Plot the error
plot(x,d(y),'r--'), hold on
legend('data','error bars','model 2')
xlabel('Time (min)'), ylabel('qt(ppm)')
```

Suggestion, I've averaged the data since, for the same x, you have 3 different samples and you can't feed that directly to the curve fitting software, or better said you shouldn't do that.

By the way, I assumed the data is in this format, since when you pasted it it wasn't clear what was x and what was y:

```
%          0         0
%          0         0
%          0         0
%     2.0000    0.0853
%     2.0000    0.0890
%     2.0000    0.0800
%     5.0000    0.3398
%     5.0000    0.3248
%     5.0000    0.3310
%    10.0000    0.6197
%    10.0000    0.6000
%    10.0000    0.6166
%    15.0000    0.9558
%    15.0000    0.9590
%    15.0000    0.8923
%    20.0000    1.0030
%    20.0000    1.0000
%    20.0000    1.0045
%    25.0000    1.0110
%    25.0000    1.0100
%    25.0000    1.0210
%    30.0000    1.0010
%    30.0000    1.0110
%    30.0000    1.0110
```